# Error calling Oracle stored procedure from Hibernate Native query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, nativequery

Consider the following codes:

```
String checkSeatQuery = "BEGIN USP_RESERVESEAT(IRESULT=>?, ICART_SESSION=>?, IEVENT_ID=>?, ISESSION_ID=>?, IPRICE_SCHEME_ID=>?, ISEAT_ID=>?, IBLOCK_ID=>?, INO_OF_SEAT=>?, IPOS=>?, ISOURCE=>?, IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY=>?); END;";
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(checkSeatQuery);
        q.setParameter(1, DataTypes.STRING); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(2, cartSessionId); //value passed in: BT71C49DD999300D33E70B69F0A43F3436
        q.setParameter(3, tblEvent.getId()); //value passed in: 20
        q.setParameter(4,null); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(5, Integer.toString(tempTicket.getTblPriceSchemes().getId())); //value passed in: 366
        q.setParameter(6, seatId); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(7, blockId); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(8, accumulatedSeat); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(9, pos); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(10, source); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(11, null); //value passed in: null

        String outputs = (String) q.getResultList().get(0);
```

Oracle procedure:

```
  DECLARE
  IRESULT VARCHAR2(200);
  ICART_SESSION VARCHAR2(200);
  IEVENT_ID NUMBER;
  ISESSION_ID NUMBER;
  IPRICE_SCHEME_ID VARCHAR2(200);
  ISEAT_ID VARCHAR2(200);
  IBLOCK_ID NUMBER;
  INO_OF_SEAT NUMBER;
  IPOS NUMBER;
  ISOURCE NUMBER;
  IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  ICART_SESSION := NULL;
  IEVENT_ID := NULL;
  ISESSION_ID := NULL;
  IPRICE_SCHEME_ID := NULL;
  ISEAT_ID := NULL;
  IBLOCK_ID := NULL;
  INO_OF_SEAT := NULL;
  IPOS := NULL;
  ISOURCE := NULL;
  IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY := NULL;

  USP_RESERVESEAT(
    IRESULT => IRESULT,
    ICART_SESSION => ICART_SESSION,
    IEVENT_ID => IEVENT_ID,
    ISESSION_ID => ISESSION_ID,
    IPRICE_SCHEME_ID => IPRICE_SCHEME_ID,
    ISEAT_ID => ISEAT_ID,
    IBLOCK_ID => IBLOCK_ID,
    INO_OF_SEAT => INO_OF_SEAT,
    IPOS => IPOS,
    ISOURCE => ISOURCE,
    IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY => IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IRESULT = ' || IRESULT);
END;
```

I got the error message:

```
2012-05-10 15:45:16,267 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-5) SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2012-05-10 15:45:16,267 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-5) ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'USP_RESERVESEAT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'USP_RESERVESEAT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Why is that? After web searching I couldn't find much helpful information..
I am using the following:
**Oracle, version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.0.0 - Production

Hibernate 3.3.2.GA**

**PL/SQL:**

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE USP_RESERVESEAT 
(
  IRESULT OUT VARCHAR2  
, ICART_SESSION IN VARCHAR2  
, IEVENT_ID IN NUMBER  
, ISESSION_ID IN NUMBER  
, IPRICE_SCHEME_ID IN VARCHAR2  
, ISEAT_ID IN VARCHAR2  
, IBLOCK_ID IN NUMBER  
, INO_OF_SEAT IN NUMBER  
, IPOS IN NUMBER  
, ISOURCE IN NUMBER  
, IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY IN VARCHAR2  
)as

     Iprice_scheme_id_inv VARCHAR2 (3000);
     Iseat_id_inv NUMBER;
     Icheck NUMBER;
     IPos1 NUMBER;
   IPos2 NUMBER;

    Icapacity NUMBER;
    Itic_sold NUMBER;
    Irv_cart NUMBER;
    Irefund_tic NUMBER;
    Irecord NUMBER;
    Irecordc NUMBER;
    Inew_seat NUMBER;

    Iavailable VARCHAR2 (3000);
    Istatus_name VARCHAR2 (3000);
    Ilatest_seat_status_key VARCHAR2 (3000);
    Ilatest_seat_status_name VARCHAR2 (3000);

    Ichild NUMBER;
    Itotal_child NUMBER;
    Icount_row NUMBER;
    Ipromo_quantity NUMBER;
    Iis_package NUMBER;

    Itocart_seat_id NUMBER;
    Ilatest_flash_seat_id VARCHAR2 (3000);
    Ipromo_tic NUMBER;
    Iallotment NUMBER;

    Iready_to_cancel NUMBER;
    Iready_to_cancel_booking_id NUMBER;
    IKILL NUMBER;
BEGIN

    if (ISOURCE = '0') THEN 
    Istatus_name := 'Internet Reserved';
    else
    if (ISOURCE = '1') THEN 
      Istatus_name :=  'POS Reserved';
    else
    if (ISOURCE = '2')  THEN 
      Istatus_name :=  'CS Reserved';
    else
    if (ISOURCE = '3') THEN 
      Istatus_name :=  'Call Centre Reserved';
    else
    if (ISOURCE = '4') THEN 
      Istatus_name :=  'Promoter Reserved';
    end IF;
  end IF;
  end IF;
  end IF;
  end IF;

  begin

                        INSERT INTO tbl_cart_session
                        (   cart_session,
              event_id,
                            price_scheme_id,
                            no_of_seat,
                            created_date
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                            Icart_session,
                            Ievent_id,
                            Iprice_scheme_id,
                            INO_OF_SEAT,
                            sysdate
                        );

      update tbl_cart_session set created_date=sysdate where cart_session=Icart_session;
            select '1' into Iresult from dual;  

  end;

END USP_RESERVESEAT;
```

Comment: what is plsql block you added ? can you show us the full declaration of `USP_RESERVESEAT` procedure ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade Hi thanks for the feedback I added the PLSQL in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The `IRESULT` is an OUT parameter so you should register it like this:

```
String checkSeatQuery = "BEGIN USP_RESERVESEAT(IRESULT=>?, ICART_SESSION=>?, IEVENT_ID=>?, ISESSION_ID=>?, IPRICE_SCHEME_ID=>?, ISEAT_ID=>?, IBLOCK_ID=>?, INO_OF_SEAT=>?, IPOS=>?, ISOURCE=>?, IFLASH_SEAT_STATUS_KEY=>?); END;";
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(checkSeatQuery);
        q.registerOutParameter(1, DataTypes.STRING); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(2, cartSessionId); //value passed in: BT71C49DD999300D33E70B69F0A43F3436
        q.setParameter(3, tblEvent.getId()); //value passed in: 20
        q.setParameter(4,null); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(5, Integer.toString(tempTicket.getTblPriceSchemes().getId())); //value passed in: 366
        q.setParameter(6, seatId); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(7, blockId); //value passed in: null
        q.setParameter(8, accumulatedSeat); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(9, pos); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(10, source); //value passed in: 1
        q.setParameter(11, null); //value passed in: null

        String outputs = (String) q.getResultList().get(0);
```

Comment: My **Query q** variable is `java.persistence.query` and it doesn't have registerOutParameter() method.  I will change my codes.   THanks!